# Meaning of "which Virginia claimed to be…she must reckon it one of the infelicitous of her position that insofar at least she was taken at her word"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> The fugitive-act did not affect a foreign country which Virginia **claimed to be** and that **she must reckon it one of the infelicitous of her position that insofar at least she was taken at her word**

This is a given example when I looked up "insofar" in a dict app. I don't know what exactly the origin is, since it doesn't matter anyway, I guess. The bolded part are those I find hardly comprehensible. Please help me restate the whole sentence into that I can readily understand.

With respect to the source: I'm sorry I really dont know, all that I can tell is that it is an randomly given example from an app"English dictionary--livio" when I searched word "insofar".

If someone does know about it, that would be very nice of you to help me edit and add the source to it as a matter of convenience.

Comment: Do you mean you "don`t know what exactly the origin is" of the quotation? It certainly does matter. Several reasons are provided [in this Meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) by one of this site's moderators. Please cite your source!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I`m afraid I cannot ,because the sentence here is just a randomly given example from "English dictionary-offline",which dosen`t even tell more than a simple sentence without any title or source of original quotation, and I just came across this one a little bit perplexing when I searched word "insofar",thus I came to ask for that.

Comment: Then the app is the source and should be cited. I see that you've identified it by name, which is helpful. (Now we know that it's probably contemporary English, people might know whether that app is credible, etc.)

Comment: I can't make any sense of it at all. I can't even parse it into English grammar structure. If your question is, "What does this sentence mean?" then the answer is "Probably nothing".

Comment: If that is typical of the examples the app uses I think it would be better to look for another app.

Comment: examples are meant to illustrate some word or grammar point.   If you understand the word you don't need to understand the example. If you don't understand the word, the problem is the word, not the example.  Asking the meaning of the example sentences in dictionaries or apps is an XY problem.  Your real problem is not understanding the example. The real problem is understanding the thing that the example is supposed to illustrate.

Comment: I suspect that "infelicitous" is a mistake for "infelicities."

Answer (score 0):

The first bold part means:
"Virginia claimed that the fugitive act DID affect a foreign country, while this is, in fact, incorrect".

The second bold part means:
"Virginia must acknowledge that, of her position, she should have known that, and it was very unfortunate she didn't. As far we we know, she was, at least, believed at the beginning".

The second part fuses two different unrelated events, thus making it a little difficult to grasp. I strongly believe that there are better transition words than **insofar** to be used here.

Though I'm quite confident about my reiteration, don't take me for my words.

Comment: "She was taken at her word" is a passive voice , so is there a possibility that it means that everybody else would believe that what she said is a actual fact for some reason even when she had herself acknowledged it as wrong ? also I wonder why the use of "infelicitous of position" here ,does it mean "a point of view or an opinion isn`t suitable for the situation" or just my imagination ,since it is in fact a "wrong" opinion,not an "unsuitable" opinion.

Comment: I definitely agree that what she stated was wrong, and there were people believing in her incorrect statements/ideas at the prior periods. I think "infelicitous of her position" simply implies that "The viewer here expected that she should've known that her statement was wrong, while she didn't know that".

Comment: And you're right again. It was very clearly implied here that her initial statement was wrong, not "unsuitable"